# how can i get file from content://com.adobe.reader.fileprovider

Tags: java, android, adobe, reader

I'm writing an Android app and I encountered problem with sharing file via my application from Adobe Acrobat Reader mobile. It works from any other application or media store. I don't know if I'm missing something.

The problem is only on Android lollipop when I want to access file. That's uri I get: content://com.adobe.reader.fileprovider/root_external/storage/emulated/0/Download/Adobe%2 0Acrobat/document.pdf

On lower versions than lollipop I get: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Adobe%20Acrobat/document.pdf which is easy to get file path from this kind of uri.

I know that on lollipop is different method for reaching real file path from uri but it doesn't work with this kind of uri I get from your application.

**I get message from Adobe Reader to use:**

For sharing files on Android Lollolop devices you may need to download the file using FileOutputStream function or you can refer:
ContentResolver | Android Developers

but when i use:

```
 InputStream inputStream =
 context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

i get:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
>   com.adobe.reader.misc.ARFileProvider

I would be thankfully for help.

With Regards, krupniok13

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace. Also, exactly how you are getting this `Uri`?

Comment: I get it from share. 

Uri fileUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

Comment: Hello, Can you please share solution? How you resolved this?